# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server After Update Directadmin

Tags: apache, centos, webserver, httpd.conf

My webserver down and cant run it again After update Directadmin

[root@srv ~]# systemctl status httpd

● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2020-06-30 10:41:18 +0430; 1min 17s ago
Process: 1363 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=killed, signal=KILL)
Main PID: 1363 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Jun 30 09:52:24 srv.shahriariboresh.ir systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...

Jun 30 10:41:13 srv.shahriariboresh.ir systemd[1]: httpd.service start operation timed out. Terminating.

Jun 30 10:41:18 srv.shahriariboresh.ir systemd[1]: httpd.service stop-sigterm timed out. Killing.

Jun 30 10:41:18 srv.shahriariboresh.ir systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL

Jun 30 10:41:18 srv.shahriariboresh.ir systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

Jun 30 10:41:18 srv.shahriariboresh.ir systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.

Jun 30 10:41:18 srv.shahriariboresh.ir systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.

any body help me for solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you please confirm are you able to start httpd using `/usr/sbin/httpd -k start ` command?

Comment: Maybe you could find more log by `journalctl -u httpd` or `journalctl -xe`